# How to read html file (loop)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have html file called 25600501.html

example file name

-25600501.html

-25600502.html

-25600503.html

-25600504.html

-25600505.html

I want to read a html file loop.

```
with open(r'C:/Users/bac/Desktop/WORK/PYTHON/25600501.html', "r") as f:
    page = f.read()
root = LH.fromstring(page)
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Are you saying you have a list of html files and you want to read all of them in a loop? Are they all local fules and are they all in the same directory? If so look at `glob` to retrieve the list of files and then loop over it opening each one in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [glob.iglob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to loop all html files in your file directory `C:/Users/bac/Desktop/WORK/PYTHON/` like this:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.iglob('C:/Users/bac/Desktop/WORK/PYTHON/*.html'): #it will loop all your html files in the dir C:/Users/bac/Desktop/WORK/PYTHON/
    with open(filename) as f:
        page = f.read()
```